# What does it mean to say " i think it's safe to say ( that ) ... "?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, phrase-usage, sentence-usage

What NAm/BrE Native speakers exactly mean when they say " i think it's safe to say ( that ) ... " ?

I mean if it's used in only one possible correct way and therefore doesn't need any further or other context.

My current understanding of it is that it is said to show that you think  that what are you going to say is based on some good reason/s and therefore it has a higher likelihood of being true or possible, is my understanding any correct or accurate?

Answer (score 1):

**It's safe to say (that)** ​is used to say that you are confident about what you are going to say:

> I think **it's safe to say** that the crisis is now over.

Comment: And by using the word confident here, do you mean that you think that you have a good reason/s why you believe sth or believe sth to be true or just the feeling of confidence alone?

Comment: It is used for saying that something is likely to be correct, so, I would guess that anyone who says that can back up what their saying.

Comment: Oh! I see now. Tanks alot!!